# Disable "photo with datetime" plus "Log in" after standby

Tags: windows-10, standby

I'm using a Convertible with Windows 10.

After standby, I touch the screen.
Instead of just going back to the desktop, I am first presented a nice but annoying photo with a beach and some info about it. On the left, date and time are shown:

[image]

To get past this screen, I have to wipe my finger upwards on the screen.
I am handicapped, and this move is really hard for me.

Next, I am shown my username and "Log in" even though I don't have a password set up. I have to click this button to show my desktop again:

[image]

I would like to get rid of all this and just jump to the desktop / activate application after the first touch on the screen while in standby.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are 3 different problems with 3 solutions:

1) I had to create the following registry folder and key:
         Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization

```
 NoLockScreen (DWORD value (32 bit), give it the value "1".
```

This will disable the "Lock Screen".

(Restart required)

2) To solve the second problem:

Win+R, then "netplwiz".
Then disable the checkbox "User need to enter username and password".

After a restart, Windows will automatically log you in.

3) To skip the login in button after sleep / standby, one needs to invoke PowerShell (Administrator) using Win+X and then doing these 2 lines:

```
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0
```